# Using DT::datatable, how to 'click' the page button automatically

Tags: r, dt

Using DT::datatable can create html table with 'page select button at' the bottom.

Is there any way can click the button automatically? (I want to show the data page by page automatically)

```
data(iris)
md <- iris
DT::datatable(md)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want?

[image]

```
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "var npages = table.page.info().pages;",
  "var i = 0;",
  "var myinterval = setInterval(function(){",
  "  if(i < npages - 1){",
  "    i = i+1;",
  "    table.page(i).draw('page');",
  "  }else{",
  "    clearInterval(myinterval)",
  "  }",
  "}, 1000);"
)

datatable(
  iris,
  callback = JS(js)
)
```